# Why calloutAccessoryControlTapped is called for tap on annotation view also?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a map on my view controller and I don't know why but the delegate `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` **is also called when I just tap on annotation view, not only when I tap on detail closure**. So why this behavior?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{    
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple developer docs:

> Accessory views contain custom content and are positioned on either
>   side of the annotation title text. If a view you specify is a
>   descendant of the UIControl class, the map view calls this method as a
>   convenience whenever the user taps your view. You can use this method
>   to respond to taps and perform any actions associated with that
>   control. For example, if your control displayed additional information
>   about the annotation, you could use this method to present a modal
>   panel with that information.
>
> If your custom accessory views are not descendants of the UIControl
>   class, the map view does not call this method.

So is your accessory view inherited from UIControl?

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:

Comment: Sorry but I can't see the point, the docs also says: **Tells the delegate that the user tapped one of the ANNOTATION VIEW'S ACCESSORY BUTTONS**. So I expected the delegate is called only for tap event on the buttons, not for the entire annotation view.

Comment: It says: "view you specify is a descendant of the UIControl class, the map view calls this method as a convenience whenever the user taps your view."

So is your accessory view inherited from UIControl?

Answer (score 1):

[Massimo Polimeni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582941/massimo-polimeni) seems to be correct.  There appears to be a problem with the rightCalloutAccessoryView, but not with the leftCalloutAccessoryView.

The code below (with a leftCalloutAccessoryView) works as expected.  If you tap the left accessory, it prints "left accessory selected".  If you tap the callout title, it doesn't print anything.

If you use a rightCalloutAccessoryView (commented out, below) and tap the right accessory, it prints "right accessory selected".  **If you tap the callout title, it also prints "right accessory selected"**.  This does not seem correct.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.29, longitude: -107.79)
        annotation.title = "Swift Current"

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        mapView.mapType = .standard
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: annotation.coordinate.latitude,
                                           longitude: annotation.coordinate.longitude),
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1.0, longitudeDelta: 1.0)
        )
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let reuseId = "Annotation"
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if view == nil {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            view?.canShowCallout = true
            view?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            //view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        } else {
            view?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return view
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
            print("left accessory selected")
        } else if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            print("right accessory selected")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of button you set on the `rightCalloutAccessoryView`. E.g. if you use:

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];`

Then both tapping the callout and tapping the button both result in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` being called with the button. But if you use:

`[UIButton systemButtonWithImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"info.circle"] target:nil action:nil];`

Then only tapping the button will work, tapping the callout will be disabled.

If you have a custom button and you want the first behavior then you can make a button subclass and do this:

```
@interface UIButton2 : UIButton

@end

@implementation UIButton2

- (id)_mapkit_accessoryControlToExtendWithCallout{
    return self;
}

@end
```

This private method is how it decides wether a button should also work for tapping the callout (learned this using [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com)). The default implementation checks `self.buttonType` to decide.

A more sensible way would be to start with the disclosure button and change its image, e.g.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
UIImage *image = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"chevron.right" withConfiguration:[UIImageSymbolConfiguration configurationWithScale:UIImageSymbolScaleSmall];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

A lot of this weird behaviour is likely to do with changes in how callout buttons work since iOS 6.