# Detect on calloutAccessoryControlTapped only the tap on rightCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uicontrol

My `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is also called when I just tap on annotation view and [this behavior it's right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432782/why-calloutaccessorycontroltapped-is-called-for-tap-on-annotation-view-also). But **how can I detect if the user has tapped on the right accessory view** (in my case a detail disclosure button) **and not just in the view?**

I added a simple check but it doesn't work.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{    
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
    {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView
        {
            ... // enter here even if I tapped on the view annotation and not on button
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve it you would need to add target for the right accessory view. You can achieve it by setting button to **rightCalloutAccessoryView** as shown in the code snippet.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is Annotation {
            let annotationView = AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
            let rightButton = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
            rightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didClickDetailDisclosure(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton
        }
        return nil
    }

    func didClickDetailDisclosure(button: UIButton) {
        // TODO: Perform action when was clicked on right callout accessory view.
    }
}

// Helper classes.
class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }
}

class AnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's no way to use just the delegate method calloutAccessoryControlTapped?

Comment: I do not know another way. If you look into Apple source code they are doing it in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using UIView and UITapGestureRecognizer instead of UIControl

   ```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
     let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
     let gestureView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20,height: 20))
     let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
     gestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(MapViewController.didClickGestureRecognizer(_:)))

     gestureView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
     gestureView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
     annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = gestureView
     return annotationView
   }    

   func didClickGestureRecognizer(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
     print("didClickGestureRecognizer")
   }
   ```

   When you click on `rightCalloutAccessoryView`, only `didClickGestureRecognizer` will be called,but your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` cannot be invoked anyone.

2.If you have a UIControl as `rightCalloutAccessoryView`,you can tap directly on MKAnnotationView.Otherwise MKAnnotationView cannot be tapped.
Both your selector and `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` will be called when you tap `rightCalloutAccessoryView` or tap directly on MKAnnotationView

3.If you have a UIControl as `leftCalloutAccessoryView`,both your selector and `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` will be called when you tapped on it.

4.Since iOS 9,you can has a `detailCalloutAccessoryView` in your MKAnnotationView.Only your selector will be called when you tapped on it.

5.Also you can create your own custom MKAnnotationView,and change its behaviors.